# Could not remove value from a CFMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cfmutabledictionary

I was trying to remove a key value pair from the dictionary with CFDictionaryRemoveValue. 
But its not removing the keys and values.Its printng me the key-value pairs after removing too.

```
struct session *value = CFDictionaryGetValue(cfmdict,tiId); 
NSLog(@"The value is %d and %c", value->a, value->c); 
CFDictionaryRemoveValue(cfmdict,tiId); 
NSLog(@"The value is %d and %c", value->a, value->c);
```

### output

```
The value is 12 and L
The value is 12 and L
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value is not in the dictionary anymore, but still in memory, and `value` still points there. Try:

```
struct session *value = (struct session *)CFDictionaryGetValue(cfmdict,tiId); 
NSLog(@"The value is %d and %c", value->a, value->c); 
CFDictionaryRemoveValue(cfmdict,tiId); 
value = (struct session *)CFDictionaryGetValue(cfmdict,tiId); 
NSLog(@"The value is %d and %c", value->a, value->c);
```

And see what happens.

Comment: @MByD:got a warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type and getting a run-time exception as EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: where do you get the warning? about the EXC_BAD_ACCESS -> that's what I wanted you to see. No value has returned now :)

Comment: I got that warning at the NSLog(@"The value is %d and %c",value->a,value->c); stmt at the last.I have inserted two values and i am removing one.

Comment: @MByD:Its working now.Thanks.Is it possible to get all the values.

Comment: @ron - yes, please refer to the documentation to see what fits your needs --> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 2):

Your first call to `CFDictionaryGetValue` returns a pointer to some struct. Then you remove the pointer to this struct from the dictionary, but that doesn’t affect the value already stored in the `value` variable.